# Can SSAS able to create 1 cube from 2 datasouces?

Tags: ssas

I am beginner to SSAS,

So, I have simple question, can we create 1 cube from 2 datasources?

And how? tq

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tutorial-tabular-1200/lesson-2-add-data?view=asallproducts-allversions#create-a-connection
You can create multiple data sources to a single cube.